# How to debug jetty+spring startup?

Tags: spring, jetty

I wonder what jetty is doing when I must wait 3 minutes?

```
2014-03-01 10:52:38.255:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.8.v20121106
2014-03-01 10:52:44.642:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
Null identity service, trying login service: null
Finding identity service: null
2014-03-01 10:55:40.464:INFO:/foobar:No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your root logger level to debug. It will help you trace what keeps jetty busy for 3 minutes.